# How to put all the values of a Integer List on unique variable on Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, integer, associative-array

I want to extract all the values of a list and put it in a variable. The list is a Integer list and the variable should also be an Integer.

```
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();

    numeros.add(1);
    numeros.add(2);
    numeros.add(3);
    numeros.add(4);

    System.out.println(numeros);
```

That gives me:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And i want to store this no a singel varaible like this:

```
System.out.println(num) //This should have all the values of the list
```

And get:

```
1234 //this as a singel variable
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post, share your attempt(s) and ask a more specific question. Also, please specify what should happen if the `Integer`-results overfloats.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();

    numeros.add(1);
    numeros.add(2);
    numeros.add(3);
    numeros.add(4);

    String num = numeros.stream()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

    System.out.println(num);
}
```

output:

```
1234
```

You can also do like this, if every element of the list is a single digit number

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();

    numeros.add(1);
    numeros.add(2);
    numeros.add(3);
    numeros.add(4);

    long num = numeros.stream()
        .mapToLong(Integer::intValue)
        .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a * 10 + b);

    System.out.println(num);
}
```

output:

```
1234
```

Comment: I like this functional approach better than my answer! I'd recommend following @saka1029's example.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of possible ways to approach this problem. One simple example:

```
int i = numeros.size();
int result = 0;
for (Integer num: numeros){
    i--;
    result += Double.valueOf(num * Math.pow(10, i)).intValue();
}
System.out.println(result);
```

However, bear in mind this has a lot of potential errors: there's no protection against exceeding [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), it assumes members of numero are single-digit numbers, etc.

If you want to control for multi-digit numbers, convert to string values and concatenate them together, then convert to an integer:

```
String holder = "";
for (Integer num: numeros){
   holder += num.toString();
int result = Integer.valueOf(holder).intValue();
System.out.println(result);
```

Also note that in both cases I'm using int for the result for simplicity. If you really need an Integer object, you can convert them using `Integer.valueOf(result)`

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(...)` returns an `int`, not an `Integer`. `int` doesn't have a `intValue()` method. Also your first code example is strange. Looks like a mix of python and java. Finally, `new Integer()` is deprecated for removal - and is not even needed here.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Actually, `Integer.valueOf()` _does_ return an integer: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int) That said, I'll edit to clean up the declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use at least `long` type to accumulate the result which would fit up to 19 decimals without overflow:

```java
static long singleNum(List<Integer> arr) {
    long res = 0;
    for (int x : arr) {
        res = 10 * res + x;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Larger input arrays could be converted into `BigInteger` (if a number is *really* needed):

```java
private static final BigInteger[] DIGIT = { 
    BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.TWO, new BigInteger("3"), new BigInteger("4"),
    new BigInteger("5"), new BigInteger("6"), new BigInteger("7"), new BigInteger("8"), new BigInteger("9")
};
static BigInteger singleNum(List<Integer> arr) {
    BigInteger res = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int x : arr) {
        res = res.multiply(BigInteger.TEN).add(DIGIT[x]);
    }
    return res;
}
```